# TikZ: identify intersection points to draw function

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to just show the part of the blue function that is strictly greater than the red one?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[/pgf/declare function={ f=2; g=1.4*(x-2); h=.1*x*x+.2*x+.5;}]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,domain=-1:20, samples=100,xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10,no markers, unit vector ratio*=1 1 1, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ]
\addplot [line width=.5pt, blue] {h};
\addplot [line width=.5pt, red] {max(f,g)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the picture
[image]

I tried with the max function but in the first part I get a weird purple color

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[/pgf/declare function={ f=2; g=1.4*(x-2); h=.1*x*x+.2*x+.5;}]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,domain=-1:20, samples=100, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10, no markers, unit vector ratio*=1 1 1, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ]
\addplot [line width=.5pt, blue] {max(f,g,h)};
\addplot [line width=.5pt, red] {max(f,g)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this is what I have right now

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As I did in my edit, you can indent lines by 4 spaces, to mark things as a [code block](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192), instead of inline code. Also, it would be great if you could turn these code blocks into complete [minimal (non-)working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that people can just copy and paste into their editor in order to help you. `:)`

Comment: Try to update `pgfplots` package, I have tested your code with version 1.12.1 and the problem don't appears.

Comment: I did it and I get the same. Right now I'm defining the domain manually with `\addplot [domain=2.2:20, line width=1pt, blue] {max(f,g,h)};`